# Google Play Warning when update to targetSdkVersion 34

Tags: google-play, targetsdkversion

I have updated `targetSdkVersion` to 34 recently in my apps because of Google letter about future rejection of the apps which targeting lower than 33.
The release was accepted and everything works fine, but I got this warning in the play console anyway.
Does someone find the answer for that? Is that related to version 34 that wasn't relesed yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning disappeared after a couple of days.

Comment: For me it actually went away after I restarted Android Studio. Thank you!